# Fragment Size with scrollview

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin

[Fragment with scrollview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SG9pS.png)

Hi guys. Here is my current design. Linear layout with scroll view on left side with buttons keeps on expanding depending how many buttons i put. What i'm trying to do is it keep it fix size and let the scroll view do it work. I keep on changing the minWidth and minHeigth and even the layout_width and layout_height in fix size but it still keeps on expanding. Any idea what im doing wrong?.Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="800dp"
    android:minHeight="600dp"
    android:weightSum="100">
<!--Top Title Bar-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="15"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:background="@drawable/AppBarBackground">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvCompanyName"
            android:fontFamily="@string/fontFamily"
            android:text="Reports"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="15"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeSmall"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
<!--Content Layout-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="85"
        android:weightSum="100">
    <!--Buttons Left Size-->
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            android:fillViewport="false">
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/BackgroundWhite">
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnXReadRpt"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:fontFamily="@string/fontFamily"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/ButtonSelectorBorderBaseColor"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/blue"
                    android:text="X-Read"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="5" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnZReadRpt"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:fontFamily="@string/fontFamily"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/ButtonSelectorBorderBaseColor"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/blue"
                    android:text="Z-Read"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="5" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnSalesRpt"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:fontFamily="@string/fontFamily"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/ButtonSelectorBorderBaseColor"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/blue"
                    android:text="Sales"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="5" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnDiscountRpt"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:fontFamily="@string/fontFamily"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/ButtonSelectorBorderBaseColor"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/blue"
                    android:text="Discount"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="5" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnItemVoidRpt"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:fontFamily="@string/fontFamily"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/ButtonSelectorBorderBaseColor"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/blue"
                    android:text="Item Void"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="5" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnTransVoidRpt"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:fontFamily="@string/fontFamily"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/ButtonSelectorBorderBaseColor"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/blue"
                    android:text="Transaction Void"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="5" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnZReadRpt"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:fontFamily="@string/fontFamily"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/ButtonSelectorBorderBaseColor"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/blue"
                    android:text="Z-Read"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="5" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnSalesRpt"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:fontFamily="@string/fontFamily"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/ButtonSelectorBorderBaseColor"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/blue"
                    android:text="Sales"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="5" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnDiscountRpt"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:fontFamily="@string/fontFamily"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/ButtonSelectorBorderBaseColor"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/blue"
                    android:text="Discount"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="5" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnItemVoidRpt"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:fontFamily="@string/fontFamily"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/ButtonSelectorBorderBaseColor"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/blue"
                    android:text="Item Void"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="5" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnTransVoidRpt"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:fontFamily="@string/fontFamily"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/ButtonSelectorBorderBaseColor"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/blue"
                    android:text="Transaction Void"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="5" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="70"
            android:weightSum="100"
            android:background="@drawable/BackgroundWhite" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What i'm trying to do is it keep it fix size and let the scroll view do it work.

Try to set a fixed size to `ScrollView` instead of using `match_parent`.

For example:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_weight="30"
    android:fillViewport="false">
...
</ScrollView>
```

And the result is:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want your layout to be fixed sized You need to set your height width fixed
i.e.

```
android:layout_width="YOUR WIDTH"
android:layout_height="YOUR_HEIGHT"
```